# Python db2 install using easy install

Tags: python-2.7, easy-install

I want to install python db2 package for Python but Im unable to install it.

I have installed the easy_install and Im able to successfully import the easy_install.

My easy_install location :c:/python27/lib/site-packages/

My db2 egg location c:/python27/ibm_db-1.0.5-py2.7-win32.egg

How would my installation command look like in the shell,

I tried this command and it gives me invalid error,

```
>>> easy_install.py c:\python27\ibm_db-1.0.5-py2.7-win32.egg
```

Comment: Have you looked at the syntax of python's easy_install?

Comment: http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall#using-easy-install

Comment: I tried it ..its not working..

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\easy_install -H None -f c:\python27\ibm_db-1.0.5-py2.7-win32.egg ibm_db
```